# A JSON text must at least contain two octets! (JSON::ParserError)

Tags: ruby, json

I'm working with a Ruby script that reads a .json file.

Here is the JSON file:

```
{
  "feed.xml": "93d5b140dd2b4779edef0347ac835fb1",
  "index.html": "1cbe25936e392161bad6074d65acdd91",
  "md5.json": "655d7c1dbf83a271f348a50a44ba4f6a",
  "test.sh": "9be192b1b5a9978cb3623737156445fd",
  "index.html": "c064e204040cde216d494776fdcfb68f",
  "main.css": "21b13d87db2186d22720e8c881a78580",
  "welcome-to-jekyll.html": "01d7c7d66bdeecd9cd69feb5b4b4184d"
}
```

It is completely valid, and is checked for its existence before trying to read from it. Example:

```
if File.file?("md5.json")
  puts "MD5s exists"
  mddigests = File.open("md5.json", "r")
  puts "MD5s" + mddigests.read
  items = JSON.parse(mddigests.read) <--- Where it all goes wrong.
  puts items["feed.xml"]
```

Everything works up until that point:

```
MD5s exists
MD5s{
  "feed.xml": "93d5b140dd2b4779edef0347ac835fb1",
  "index.html": "1cbe25936e392161bad6074d65acdd91",
  "md5.json": "655d7c1dbf83a271f348a50a44ba4f6a",
  "test.sh": "9be192b1b5a9978cb3623737156445fd",
  "index.html": "c064e204040cde216d494776fdcfb68f",
  "main.css": "21b13d87db2186d22720e8c881a78580",
  "welcome-to-jekyll.html": "01d7c7d66bdeecd9cd69feb5b4b4184d"
}
common.rb:156:in `initialize': A JSON text must at least contain two octets! (JSON::ParserError)
```

I've searched and tried a lot of different things, to no avail. I'm stumped. Thanks!

Comment: Does this still occur if you comment out the first middigests.read?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a duplicate call to `read()` at the point that it all goes wrong.  Replace the second call to `read()` with the variable `mddigests` and all should be fine.

This code should work like you'd expect:

```
if File.file?("md5.json")
  puts "MD5s exists"
  mddigests = File.open("md5.json", "r")
  digests = mddigests.read
  puts "MD5s" + digests
  items = JSON.parse(digests)   #<--- This should work now!
  puts items["feed.xml"]
end
```

The reason is that the file pointer is moved after the first `read()`, and by the second `read()`, it's at the end of file, hence the message requiring at least 2 octets.

Comment: thank you so much! Thats kinda weird, but I guess thats how ruby works :)